# SSH connection refused when connecting remotly

Tags: networking, server, ssh, connection, firewall

I set up my Ubuntu server and it can connect to itself when running `ssh localhost`. However, when I run Putty on windows 8 I get a "connection refused" error.
I have, to the best of my ability:

- disabled the firewall
- double checked port number in putty
- allowed putty in my windows firewall (I can connect to other servers fine)
- reinstalled ssh

When trying to connect with putty I am using `127.0.0.1` and port 22 (I did not change the port number on my server from default).
I think the problem is that the server isn't allowing external devices to connect to it still but if it isn't the firewall then I'm not quite sure where to look, I'm not the linux Guru I wish I was but I know enough to get by with most things.

Additionally, I realize there have been many posts on this connection refused error, however I just spent all day reading through them and I couldn't find anything that looked relevant to the issues I am experiencing

Comment: First of all its a good idea to verbose the connection to get more details: ssh -v user@host

Comment: can you telnet to it?
telnet <host-address> 22

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address, always pointing to the current machine. Original poster possibly doesn’t understand it.

Answer (score 4):

If I am reading your question right, it sounds like you are using putty on windows, to connect to ubuntu. It also sounds like you are giving putty the IP `127.0.0.1`. If that is the case, you are telling putty to connect to your windows computer. To find the IP on ubuntu, you could run `ip addr show` (on the ubuntu computer), then use the IP address for the interface you are using for internet (en0, wlan0, etc) with putty.

Comment: okay i will try that right now and update this

Comment: okay so now when I attempt to ssh with my servers ip address (using putty on windows) I get "Network error: Connection timed out" and my internet is working on both systems

Comment: @michael Are your two machines are on the same router, or different networks? They way you wrote your question it is hard to tell which.

Comment: I used the above method to obtain my ip, before i was running sbin/ifconfig and I think I was typing in the ip for the wrong interface, anyhow, I just successfully signed on through putty, thanks!

Comment: @michael: please accept the answer so that others can see that your question lead to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to install SSH on the server:
sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Hope this helps a fellow newbe running Win 8 with Ubuntu 13.04 as a guest OS in VMWare Player

Comment: +1 for help me solve my problems but actually I think you get downvote because this solution is not answer the OP question exactly.